# How can I use keychain when I close my ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I'm developing an iOS app and want user only type username:password pair only once (unless he logs out). Currently I use [keychain-swift](https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift) framework for storing emails/passwords.

I basically run:

```
let keychain = KeychainSwift()
keychain.set("johndoe", forKey: "my key") // on a successful login
keychain.get("my key")
```

When I run my app in a simulator I have to type password all the time (i.e., it doesn't look like it saves the password in keychain between the sessions).

Is it expected? What framework will allow me to save the data even when I close the app such that a user won't have to type `username:password` pairs every time to sign in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used `KeychainSwift` but at a guess you could do something like:

```
let keychain = KeychainSwift(keyPrefix: "com.Daniel.myIOSapp.")
keychain.set("johndoe", forKey: "username")
keychain.set("where is jane", forKey: "password")
```

which will create two "generic password" keychain items `com.Daniel.myIOSapp.username` and `com.Daniel.myIOSapp.password` and the associated values.

You normally store the username/password pair as a *single* keychain item. You can do that with `KeychainSwift` using something like:

```
keychain.set("where is jane", forKey: "johndoe")
```

which creates a single generic password item in the keychain and you probably want to store `"johndoe"` in your *preferences* under a suitable key.

HTH

Comment: Could you be more specific about _storing "johndoe" in your preferences under a suitable key_? Like what do you mean by _preferences_?

Comment: By preferences I mean `UserDefaults`. If you store the username/password as a key/value pair in the keychain you need some way of remembering/finding the username so you can use it as the key to get the password; one option is to store the username only in the preferences, so you get the username from preferences and then the password from the keychain.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used this framework myself, but from looking at the code it appears that it will save, and therefore be accessible after app is restarted.

You might want to confirm the `set` function is working properly. From the readme here:

https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift/blob/master/README.md

...it states:

> Check if operation was successful
>
> One can verify if set, delete and clear methods finished successfully
>   by checking their return values. Those methods return true on success
>   and false on error.
>
> if keychain.set("hello world", forKey: "my key") {   // Keychain item
>   is saved successfully } else {   // Report error }

Also, just to confirm, the get function should read:

```
let myKey = keychain.get("my key")
```

...where `myKey` is put into your text field(s).